# How to break reordering in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Can I break/stop current reordering of rows in UITableView (programmatically) without reloading tableView?

Comment: You cann't do any changes in tableview cell without reloading? At least, just reload corresponding cells.

Comment: I need delete programatically some cells with animations, but if user drags some cell at same time, it violates the order or crash app. And how I can delete cell, which the user drags now?

Comment: Do you mean while the user is actively dragging, or do you mean that the table view is in edit mode, and some cells may have been reordered?

Comment: I mean while the user is actively dragging..
When user drags cell but doesn't drop yet...